# Concat list and observable list

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Let's say I have 3 lists. Two of them are basic lists while the last one is an observable.

The issue is I now want to merge a non-observable list into the observable one.
Right now I do something like this but I feel like it's "against observables' nature"

```
listToMerge = []
listObs$: BehaviorSubject<[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
listObsCopy = []
```

I already added some elements in the listObs with the next method

```
listObs$.next(someStuff);
listObsCopy = somestuff;
```

Here is my attempt to merge them.

```
listToMerge = listObsCopy.concat(someOtherStuff);
listObs$.next(listToMerge as any);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? It will merge all arrays into a single one using RxJS.

```
    import { BehaviorSubject, merge } from 'rxjs';
    import { concatAll, take, tap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

    // Subject (and Observable with take(1) to force completion.)
    let listSubject: BehaviorSubject<string[]> = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>(['B1', 'B2']);
    let listObs$ = listSubject.asObservable().pipe(take(1));

    // List to Merge 
    let listToMerge = ['1', '2'];

    let mergedObs$ = merge(listToMerge, listObs$).pipe(concatAll(), toArray());

    mergedObs$.subscribe((value) => console.log('merged array:', value));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ukxwep?file=index.ts

The trick is in using concatAll() operator to flatten all arrays and then use toArray() operator to make 1 array out of that.

Note that I've added take(1) to the observable for the subject. The subscribe will only start when the Observable ends.

Comment: My goal was more to remove listObjCopy if possible  
would it be an option with this?  
```listObs$ = merge(listObs$, of(listToMerge).pipe(concatAll(),  toArray()); ```

Comment: That will work. See https://typescript-ukxwep.stackblitz.io

Comment: Please note that this will overwrite the previous context. I recommend to use a new variable for this. So: `let mergeArrayObs$ = merge(listObs$, of(listToMerge).pipe(concatAll(), toArray());`

Comment: the stackblitz link doesn't seems to work but thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Note that you don't need the `of` on the arrays. You can pass the array directly to merge. Like this: `let mergedArray$ = merge(listObsCopy, listToMerge, listObs$)`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create an observable from your array to then concat them using the `from()` function:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from

```
const arraySource = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const arraySource2 = from([6, 7, 8]);
arraySource.concat(arraySource2).subscribe()
```

Comment: I didn't know of the from method, but would it work to do something like this?  

```listToMerge = from(someOtherStuff)
listObs$.concat(listToMerge).subscribe()  
```

and then having   
listObs values = oldListObs + listToMerge